# InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: java, junit, mockito, matcher, hamcrest

I'm busy with writing a Junit test with Mockito.

Now I want to verify something like this:

```
verify(event).fire(
   new DefaultMonitoringEventImpl(
      any(Class.class), any(MonitorEventType.class), MonitorEventLevel.ALL, anyString()
   )
  );
```

I only care about the third parameter.
when I try this I get a: InvalidUseOfMatchersException.

Whatever i try it wont fix this issue.
Related topics won's give a satisfied solution.

-Bgvv1983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ArgumentCaptor](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html):

```
ArgumentCaptor<DefaultMonitoringEventImpl> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(DefaultMonitoringEventImpl.class);
Mockito.verify(event).fire(captor.capture());
DefaultMonitoringEventImpl actual = captor.getValue();
Assert.assertEquals(MonitorEventLevel.ALL, actual.getMonitorEventLevel());
```

Comment: Thank, stupid I haven't thought of that. One little remark on your solution though.

    Mockito.verify(event).fire(captor); 

must be: Mockito.verify(event).fire(captor.capture());